# Is there an easy way of text searching using lookup tables in R? (Version 2 - multiple word searching)

Tags: r, inner-join, lookup

I've previously asked a very similar question which was superbly answered but I have since slightly changed the search terms to multiple words so I am posting a fresh question with updated code/example.

I have a use case where I have lots of 'lookup tables', i.e. dataframes containing strings I am searching for in rows within a large second dataframe. I need to extract rows where a string exists within the dataframe but there may be other strings in the dataframe. I also need to extract the whole row and that of the lookup table when a match is found.

I've successfully achieved what I need via a nested for loop, but my actual dataset is massive and the lookup table will be circa 50,000 rows. So a for loop is going to be very inefficient. I have had success using dplyr::semi_join but that only works when the entries match exactly, whereas I am searching for a single word in a longer string:

```
fruit_lookup <- data.frame(fruit=c("banana drop","apple juice","pear","plum"), rating=c(3,4,3,5))
products <- data.frame(product_code=c("535A","535B","283G","786X","765G"), product_name=c("banana drop syrup","apple juice concentrate","melon juice","coconut oil","strawberry jelly"))
results <- data.frame(product_code=NA, product_name=NA, fruit=NA, rating=NA)

for(i in 1:nrow(products)) {
  for(j in 1:nrow(fruit_lookup)){
    if(stringr::str_detect(products$product_name[i], fruit_lookup$fruit[j])) {
      results <- tibble::add_row(results)
      results$product_code[i] <- products$product_code[i]
      results$product_name[i] <- products$product_name[i]
      results$fruit[i] <- fruit_lookup$fruit[j]
      results$rating[i] <- fruit_lookup$rating[j]
      break
    }
    }
  }

results <- stats::na.omit(results)
print(results)
```

This yields the result I am wanting:

```
product_code     product_name                 fruit         rating
535A             banana drop syrup            banana drop   3
535B             apple juice concentrate      apple juice   4
```

Any advice gratefully received and I won't be hurt if I have missed something obvious. Please feel free to critique my other coding practices, which may not be ideal!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a regex-join. Up-front, I'm not certain how well this scales with any of the offerings:

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_inner_join(products, fruit_lookup, by = c("product_name" = "fruit"))
#   product_code            product_name       fruit rating
# 1         535A       banana drop syrup banana drop      3
# 2         535B apple juice concentrate apple juice      4
```

Similarly, `sqldf`:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  select p.*, f.*
  from fruit_lookup f
    inner join products p on  p.product_name like '%'||f.fruit||'%'
")
```